# Jeffrey Lee 2.11 Show there is a nice map $s:TTM \to TTM$ satisfying several properties

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm not sure this problem makes any sense on several levels, but here is the question verbatim:

> Find natural coordinates for the double tangent bundle $TTM$. Show that there is a nice map $s:TTM \to TTM$ such that $s\circ s = \text{id}_{TTM}$ and such that $T\pi \circ s = T\pi_{TM}$ and $T\pi_{TM} \circ s = T\pi$. Here $\pi:TM \to M$ and $\pi_{TM}:TTM \to TM$ are the appropriate tangent bundle projection maps.

The first part is not an issue. The rest is what bothers me.

$T\pi \circ s = T\pi_{TM}$ does not make sense since the map on the left is from $TTM \to TM$ and the one on the right is from $TTTM \to TTM$.

$T\pi_{TM} \circ s = T\pi$ does not make sense either since the maps on the left do not even compose, and even if they did, the one on the left would be from $TTM \to TTM$ whereas the one on the right is from $TTM \to TM$.

I have been trying to see if there is any way to rectify the situation, but any adjustment in domains and codomains solves one problem but leads to another. Since I doubt this nonsense question could have made it into the textbook unless there was a typo, I was wondering if anyone sees how to make sense of this problem by fixing something.

Comment: I think it should simply be "$T\pi \circ s = \pi_{TM}$" and "$\pi_{TM} \circ s = T\pi$". Then the domains and codomains line up and, additionally, $s \circ s = \operatorname{id}_{TTM}$ lets you jump between the two quoted conditions: If we have $T\pi \circ s = \pi_{TM}$ then $T \pi =T\pi \circ( s \circ s)= (T\pi \circ s) \circ s = \pi_{TM} \circ s$.

Comment: Okay thanks! I found the map $s$ then by switching the first $n$ coordinates of the tangent vector in $T_{(p,v)}TM$ with the coordinates of $v \in T_pM$.

Comment: Looks good to me.  I think this called the canonical involution on $TTM$ and has an interpretation in terms of the equivalence of mixed partial derivatives.